# Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add', Categories name dont show up Django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to let user create a post and select a category, but when it selects a category and I post it, it gives me the error: Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'.
If i go to my database, whatever I type, it is save except the category_id which is null.

This is my code

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def userposts_create_view(request):
  form= UserPostForm(request.POST or None)
  #print(request.POST)
  if request.POST:# form.is_valid():
    #data = form.cleaned_data
    #print(data)
    #categories = data.pop('categories', None)
    categories = request.POST['categories']
    content = request.POST['content']
    title = request.POST['title']
    public = False
    if 'public' in request.POST and request.POST['public'] == 'on':
        public = False
    else:
        public=True
    #print(f"{categories}, {content}, {title}, {public}")
    #user_post = UserPost.objects.create(**data, user=request.user)
    user_post = UserPost.objects.create(content=content, title=title, public=public, user=request.user)#, categories=categories)

    categories = Categories.objects.filter(name=Categories.name)
    print(categories)
    user_post.categories.get(categories)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/posted/")

 context= {'form': form}

 return render(request, 'posts/userposts-create-view.html', context)



#list view
@login_required(login_url='login')
def userposts_list_view(request):

    allposts= UserPost.objects.all()
    
    context= {'allposts': allposts,
              }
    
    return render(request, 'posts/userposts-list-view.html', context)


#detail view
@login_required(login_url='login')
def userposts_detail_view(request, id=None):

    post= get_object_or_404(UserPost, id=id)

    context= {'post': post,
              }
    
    return render(request, 'posts/userposts-detail-view.html', context)
```

I assume the error must be in the models but not sure...

Models.py

```
class Categories(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nombre')



def __str__(self):
    return self.name

User= settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class UserPost(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, editable=False, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    content= models.TextField(null=False)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Privada?',default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Creado el ')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Actualizado el ')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.user)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserPost


class UserPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= UserPost
        fields= ["title", "content","categories","public"]
```

create_view.html

```
{%extends 'layouts/layout.html'%}

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
{% block title %}
Post
{% endblock title %}

</head>
<body>


<h1>Create Post</h1>
{% block content %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('articulos/', views.list, name = "list_articles"), #se utilizaria page para el menu
    path('categoria/<int:category_id>', views.category, name="category"),
    path('articulo/<int:article_id>', views.article, name="article"),
    path('create/', views.userposts_create_view, name='create'),
    path('posted/', views.userposts_list_view, name='list_view'),
    path('posted/<int:id>', views.userposts_detail_view, name='one_posts'),
    path('tus_ideas', views.index_page, name='tus_ideas')

]
```

Comment: `categories = models.ForeignKey('Categories', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` please change this to `categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. Not use single quotes .

Comment: @RiyasAc I did it but is still giving me the same issue

Comment: please add your urls.py file and html template

Comment: Just added the urls and html templates @RiyasAc, it is giving me this error now  Exception Value: 
'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object is not iterable

Comment: please change `categories = Categories.objects.filter(name=Categories.name)` to `categories = Categories.objects.filter(name=c.name)`

Comment: I've made some changes and now is telling me Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' on the line: user_post.categories.get(categories) @RiyasAc

Comment: `user_post.categories.get(categories)` please comment this line. it doesnot use after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220369/discussion-between-enrique-gil-garcia-and-riyas-ac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def userposts_create_view(request):
  form= UserPostForm(request.POST or None)
  if request.POST:
    categories = request.POST['categories']
    content = request.POST['content']
    title = request.POST['title']
    public = False
    if 'public' in request.POST and request.POST['public'] == 'on':
      public = False
    else:
      public=True
    
    user_post = UserPost.objects.create(content=content, title=title, public=public, user=request.user,categories_id=categories)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/posted/")
  context= {'form': form}
  return render(request, 'posts/userposts-create-view.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

`user_post.categories.add(*categories)` would work if `categories` is a `ManyToMany` field in your `UserPost` model whereas it it a `ForeignKey` in your code.

Change your `categories` fields to :

```py
class UserPost(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Categories', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! and you may know why when I see the post, on the ideas section this shows up: blog.Categories.None

Comment: You need to display those categories with a for loop : `{% for cat in user_post.categories.all %}{{ cat.name }}{% endfor %}`